# Is there a 'standard way' to parse about:blank URL's in Java?

Tags: java, url, protocols

With the following code fragment, if docurl = "about:blank", then I get a java.net.MalformedURLException thrown. I cant believe I am the first person to have to handle such urls so Im wondering if there is a different api than java.net I can use?

```
        try {
            URL url;
            url = new URL(docurl);
            docuri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), null);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Is `about:blank` itself standard?

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-holsten-about-uri-scheme-06

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the "about" protocol not having a valid handler.

The valid handlers for my jre6 installation are found in rt.jar

```
sun/net/www/protocol/ftp/Handler.class
sun/net/www/protocol/gopher/Handler.class
sun/net/www/protocol/http/NegotiateCallbackHandler.class
sun/net/www/protocol/mailto/Handler.class
sun/net/www/protocol/netdoc/Handler.class
sun/net/www/protocol/http/Handler.class
sun/net/www/protocol/jar/Handler.class
sun/net/www/protocol/file/Handler.class
```

You can make your own handler class by following the recipe at 
http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/protocolhandlers/

Answer (score 0):

You can parse such URLs with **[java.net.URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)**.

Alternatively, I wrote a Java URL parsing library that offers a more general solution: [galimatias](https://github.com/smola/galimatias).